# Serialize datagridview to a xml file not working

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, xml-serialization

I know this is a very simple and basic question but I would like to know how to fix this. I got a problem in serializing the object from the datagrdiview.

This line is not working for me in the

```
if (dataGridView1 != null) 
    _example.Details = dataGridView1.DataBindings;   // Not Working.
```

Please tell me what is the mistake I'm doing here...! Thank you.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //Read
{
            XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLExample));
            XMLExample _example = new XMLExample();

            // Read file.
            using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\test\testserialization.xml"))
            {
                _example = (XMLExample)_serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
                textReader.Close();
            }

            textBox1.Text = _example.ID;
            textBox2.Text = _example.Initial;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = _example.Details;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Write
        {
            XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLExample));
            XMLExample _example = new XMLExample();

            _example.ID = textBox1.Text;
            _example.Initial = textBox2.Text;

            List<Detail> _source = new List<Detail>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                _source.Add(new Detail
                {
                    FirstName = "Name_" + i,
                    LastName = "Surname_" + i,
                    Section = "section_"+i,
                });
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = _source;

            if (dataGridView1 != null && dataGridView1.DataSource != null) 
               _example.Details = (List<Detail>)dataGridView1.DataSource;

            using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test\testserialization.xml"))
            {
                _serializer.Serialize(textWriter, _example);
                textWriter.Close();
            }
        }
```

The class file:

```
[Serializable]
public class StudentInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string UserID { get; set; } // Textbox1
    public string Department { get; set; } // Textbox2
    public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Detail // Datagridview1
{
    [XmlElement("FirstName")] //Datagridview
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("LastName")] //Datagridview
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Section")] //Datagridview
    public string Section { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (dataGridView1 != null && dataGridView1.DataSource != null) test.Details = (List<Detail>)dataGridView1.DataSource;
```

Sample code with assignment `List<Detail>` to property DataSource of DataGridView object (add this code in constructor):

```
 List<Detail> _source = new List<Detail>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                _source.Add(new Detail
                {
                    FirstName = "Name_" + i,
                    LastName = "Surname_" + i,
                    Section = "Section_" + i
                });
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = _source;
```

Comment: Where you assigned DataSource?

Comment: I just copied your snippet and tried. I didn't assign any datasource except your snippet. Do i have to assign one?

Comment: @ kmatyaszek: ...my problem is how to edit the datagrid and write it back to the xml file.?? Thank you

Comment: @linguini try add in constructor my sample code after `InitializeComponent();` only for test. And after that change, probably in your event handler change that one line which I suggested you above. I try this and it's working. If it's not working in your solution, you must give me more code, especially code where you assign data to DataGridView.

Comment: @linguini and what happening if you invoke button2_Click now? And why you use this `new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLExample));` instead of this `new XmlSerializer(typeof(StudentInfo));`. Where is defined XMLExample class?

Comment: @ kmatyaszek: Sorry that was a mistake. I still have the same problem. I'll share my project in microsft ..can u assist me?? Thank you.

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8FE34CB77340CAA9!149&authkey=!AGYx8J6hdIzjD2A

Comment: @linguini it's working ;) This data are correctly serialized to file. If you want you can delete columns which are added. This columns will be auto generated.

Answer (score 1):

You must serilaize not dataGridView, and DataTable or DataSource

Example:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataTable));
DataTable dt = new DataTable("data");
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath+"\\"+fname+".xml");
ser.Serialize(writer, dt);
writer.Close();
```

Comment: I'm trying to serialize the object of the list through datagridview.